# sizeof(array_of_char) outputs strange number

Tags: c, sizeof

I'm writing this code to use sizeof() function with a char array of 7 elements, I thought that the output should be 8 because of the 7 elements PLUS the terminator of the array but surprised that the output was 5?? HOW COME?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[]="S\065AB";
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(str));

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\065` is a single character, represented as an octal escape sequence.

Comment: What do you mean with "octal escape sequence"?
and how did you know that it's octal and what are the other examples like this?

Comment: @Salahuddin: It's octal because of the leading `0`. Other examples are `\064` and `\066`.

Comment: So if I want to write just '0' it's OK write just '0', but if I want to write octal i've to write '\0' then the ocatal number right?
You didn't tell me what do you mean with "escape sequence"?

Comment: `\0` is also an octal escape sequence, whose value is zero.

Comment: @Salahuddin maybe he didn't tell you what he meant because the trusted you to be able to google it by yourself.

Comment: I read about escape sequence and knew that \0 is the octal escape sequence, but what is the equivelant of this escape sequence? , I mean that \n means new line, \\ means a backslash, so what does octal scape sequence prints?, when I printed the array, the output was "S5AB" so \06 has vanished and no equivelant appeared??

Comment: @Salahuddin: The escape sequence represents a single `char` of that value. Remember that a `char` is just a number, so `'\06'` is the number 6. (It probably doesn't have a printable meaning in your character set, though. Pipe it into a hex editor maybe.)

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
char str[]="S\\065AB";
```

instead of

```
char str[]="S\065AB";
```

`\065` is a C escape sequence.